# error: bool' cannot be declared with 'explicit' specifier

Tags: c++, explicit

When I use the `explicit` with `bool` to convert a parameter I get this error:

> error C2178:  'sdds::Ship::operator bool' cannot be declared with 'explicit' specifier.

My objective with this function was to use it to convert a `bool` operator that returns true if the object is valid, and false otherwise.

```
explicit Ship::operator bool() const
    {
        bool check = true;
        if (m_type == nullptr && strlen(m_type) == 0 && m_engines[0].get() > 0 && m_engCnt == 0)
        {
            check = false;
        }
        return check;
    }
```

Here is my class:

```
class Ship
    {
        Engine m_engines[10];
        char m_type[TYPE_MAX_SIZE];
        int m_engCnt;
... public:
explicit operator bool() const;
...
```

Comment: Try dropping the `explicit` keyword from the definition, and only use it in the declaration.

Answer (score 2):

`explicit` couldn't be specified for out-of-class member function definition; it should be specified only inside the class definition.

So remove it as

```
Ship::operator bool() const
{
    bool check = true;
    if (m_type == nullptr && strlen(m_type) == 0 && m_engines[0].get() > 0 && m_engCnt == 0)
    {
        check = false;
    }
    return check;
}
```